# live function undefined if I call it

Tags: jquery

I have a live function which I also want to be able to call. I realize I cannot call it but I am not sure how to approach this. When I try to call the live function it comes up as undefined. Anyone have any suggestions on how to handle this? I want to be able to call the function without clicking the #open-window link and pass it different information to open a window when different circumstances occur. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
$('#open-window').live('click', function openwindow() {
var user=$(this).attr('data-name');
//...and then append some information
});

openwindow(somevariable);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your function in a lesser scope than you need it. Reverse it.

```
function openwindow(somevariable) {
   var user=$(this).attr('data-name');
   //...and then append some information
}

openwindow(somevariable);
$('#open-window').live('click', openwindow);
```

Comment: Will `$(this)` still refer to anything meaningful if you use the function outside of an event handler context?

Comment: nope. At that point it will refer to the window object. I'm assuming he's using the variable `somevariable` to get data when used in a window context

Answer (score 2):

A named function expression is not meant to leak that name to the outside scope; it should be used only to make the function recursive.

Note that [IE erroneously does leak the name](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

Comment: Thanks Alex, what does recursion mean with regards to a function?

Comment: @Scarface [Wikipedia has a nice article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
function openwindow() {
  var user=$(this).attr('data-name');
  //...and then append some information
}

$('#open-window').live('click', openwindow);

openwindow(somevariable);
```